# Automate Chrome Extensions With Selenium and Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium

I am currently working on an automation project where I need to use Ruby/Selenium to discover specific http headers returned to the user after authentication to a web app. I am able to automate the web app just fine; however, when I try to use a Chrome extension the browser returns the following error:

*The webpage at chrome-extension://[extension address] might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.*

After looking into this, it appears that the Selenium web driver is using a different Chrome profile than my regular Chrome profile. As such, I was wondering if someone knew if there is a way to to tell Selenium to use my regular Chrome profile with the extension loaded or build a new profile and install the extension during runtime.

So far, most of the answers I have found were centralized around Python and Java. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To launch Chrome with the default profile on Windows:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

switches = ['user-data-dir='+ENV['LOCALAPPDATA']+'\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data']
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => switches

driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.co.uk"
```

Or to add an extension to the created profile:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, 
  :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome({
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'extensions' => [
        Base64.strict_encode64(File.open('C:\\App\\extension.crx', 'rb').read)
      ]
    }
  })

driver.navigate.to "https://www.google.co.uk"
```

Comment: I tried the same for firefox but it is not working. What changes should I make other than replacing 'chrome' with 'firefox' and the extension name?